# Finding PEAK (not just max) values through a range?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm building an exercise tracker with DATE, EXERCISE, VALUE column. I'm racking my brain to come up with a formula that could populate a new column with the last maximum value of each exercise according to date. i.e.

[image]

So in this case, my performance history for exercise A is:

```
1,10,100,10,1000,10,100
```

Last maxes should be

```
1,10,100,100,1000,1000,1000
```

So far, I've managed to sort the VALUE by last largest (though cells that are not MAX are "", instead of filling with last MAX value) with

```
=if(COUNTIF(MAX($C1:C$2),C1),C1,"")
```

but can't figure out how to discriminate and track last largest of individual exercise. I can also

Comment: Providing a sample sheet can be helpful to those answering the question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is in columns A-C, starting at row 2, this formula, when copy/pasted into the group max column, will give you want you want:

```
=max(filter(filter($A$2:$Cx, $B$2:$Bx=Bx), {false, false, true}))
```

where x = current row.

[image: Working example]

Explanation:

- The innermost filter() takes into account only all rows until now from the current row's group
- the outermost filter() limits the result to the 3rd column
- max() takes the max of that column.

A challenge: can this answer be improved to a single ARRAYFORMULA that would not require copying/pasting? I was not able to do it.

Comment: Tried in various configurations e.g. this: 

=ArrayFormula(max(if(B$2:B13=B2:B13,C$2:C13)))

but it does not expand to the whole range.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:

```
=ArrayFormula(max(if(K$2:K2=K2,L$2:L2)))
```